# Hide and Show createBottomTabNavigator tabbar with Animation in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am using `createBottomTabNavigator` for tab bar.

I can hide and show tabbar using `tabBarVisible` prop by setting it `true` or `false`.

Problem I have is ,I want it to hide with animation.

any links will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might wanna use new Animated.Value(0)
And change the bottom value of the tab.
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/888 this has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom `tabBarComponent`, and then hide/show it with what animation you want. I catch the props of `tabbar` in `componentWillReceiveProps`

I used `react-native-animatable` for animation.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    const oldState = this.props.navigation.state;
    const oldRoute = oldState.routes[oldState.index].routes[0];
    const oldParams = oldRoute.params;
    const wasVisible = !oldParams || oldParams.visible;

    const newState = props.navigation.state;
    const newRoute = newState.routes[newState.index].routes[0];
    const newParams = newRoute.params;
    const isVisible = !newParams || newParams.visible;

    if (wasVisible && !isVisible) {
      this.view.slideOutDown(500);
      this.setState({
        hidden: true,
      });
    } else if (isVisible && !wasVisible) {
     this.view.slideInUp(500).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        hidden: false,
      });
    });
    } 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Animatable.View
        ref={ref => { this.view = ref; }}
        style={[styles.container, {
          position: this.state.hidden ? 'absolute' : 'relative',
        }]}
        useNativeDriver
      >
        <BottomTabBar
          {...this.props}
        />
      </Animatable.View>
    );
  }
```